# javascript module loading flow in browsers 2020 and anyway to optimise (download only when needed)

Tags: javascript, html, browser, es6-modules

I am using vanilla javascript as modules and directly loading them in the browser like this

```
<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
```

obviously the app.js uses imported modules from other files as well.
What I see in the browser [latest(March 2020) chrome & firefox] dev tools is waterfall of network requests to fetch all the nested modules.

Some of the modules are referenced in the import but they are used only when a user performs a specific action.

Is downloading all modules with import reference the standard spec by browsers and it is going to stay this way? I suspect www specs are always evolving and I am sure there are smarter folks out there handling it, so they must have thought and solved this issue way before me reaching this point. right?

Is there a workaround to tell the browser to fetch modules only when the app actually needs them and no need to pull a deluge of modules at the first load?

I am using pure vanilla JS without any bundlers, webpack, babel etc.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there is an [`import()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports), and it doesn't even need to be called from a `module` script.

```js
const script_url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
  `export const foo = "hello, world";`
], { type: 'application/javascript' }));

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = async(evt) => {
  const mymodule = await import(script_url);
  console.log(mymodule.foo);
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">fetch my module</button>
```